# IllegalArgumentException: Pointcut is not well-formed: expecting '('

Tags: spring, aspectj, spring-aop, pointcut

What is wrong with my pointcut?

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
  Pointcut is not well-formed:
  expecting '(' at character position 0
  ru.ssau.tk.Ildar.Sandbox.spring.aop.mypractice.aspects.PointCuts.forAddBook
```

My pointcut:

```java
@Pointcut("execution(* ru.ssau.tk.Ildar.Sandbox.spring.aop.mypractice.Library.addBook())")
public void forAddBook() {}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. The pointcut looks OK to me, other than your package structure with upper-case package names looking a bit ugly. But if the package name is like that indeed, it should work. If it does not, please provide more information, ideally an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) on GitHub, so I can reproduce the problem. It looks like a practice project, so maybe you can even share it directly without morphing confidential code into an MCVE.

Comment: Please be kind enough to provide some feedback to the people who are trying to help you. Saying nothing is simply not very polite.

Comment: I'am really sorry,I could not figure out what the problem was, in the end I deleted the entire project and made it again. Everything is working now

Comment: Then please delete the question. There is no point in keeping an unanswered question for a non-reproducible problem around. And next time, provide timely feedback to the community you requested help from. Thank you.